# React Native Register Button issue

Tags: javascript, react-native

In the React Native application, the button continues to operate when the information is entered incorrectly on the member entry and registration page. The button is not activated again to re-enter information. Could you help?

In other words, when the information is entered incorrectly or missing, the registration button is rotating continuously.

Please review the screenshot and codes.

**Screenshot:**

[![Screen shot with the UI][1]][1]

My codes are:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Dimensions, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const LogoImg = require('../assets/img/challengelogo.png');
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as  appActions from './actions';

export class signupView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checkboxChecked: false,
            checkboxIcon: 'ios-square-outline'
        }
    }

    render() {

      const { container, innerContainer, innerImageContainer, buttonView , buttonViewRegister, innerButtonTextView, innerButtonView, termsView} = styles;
      return (
        <LinearGradient
          colors={['#f9a149', '#e86e52', '#d6375c']}
          style={ container }>
          <KeyboardAwareScrollView
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
          style={styles.scrollContainer}>
           <View  style={innerContainer}>
                <Image
                source={LogoImg}
                style={{ width: width*0.45, height: width*0.55 }}
                resizeMode={'contain'}
                />
                <View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
                    <Text style={{color:'#fff', fontSize:18, margin:10, textDecorationLine:'underline'}} >KAYIT OL</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.searchSection}>
                    <Icon style={styles.searchIcon} name="ios-person-add" size={30} color="#000"/>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı"
                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                        autoCapitalize = 'none'
                        autoCorrect = {false}
                        value = {this.props.r_name}
                        onChangeText={this._onNameChanged.bind(this)}
                        autoFocus = { true }
                        blurOnSubmit = { false }
                        returnKeyType = { "next" }
                        onSubmitEditing = {() => {this.mailTextInput.focus()} }
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.searchSection}>
                    <Icon style={styles.searchIcon} name="ios-mail-outline" size={30} color="#000"/>
                    <TextInput
                        ref={(input) => { this.mailTextInput = input; }}
                        style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Mail Adresi"
                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                        keyboardType="email-address"
                        autoCapitalize = 'none'
                        autoCorrect = {false}
                        value = {this.props.r_email}
                        onChangeText={this._onEmailChanged.bind(this)}
                        blurOnSubmit = { false }
                        returnKeyType = { "next" }
                        onSubmitEditing = {() => {this.passwordTextInput.focus()} }
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.searchSection}>
                    <Icon style={styles.searchIcon} name="md-lock" size={30} color="#000"/>
                    <TextInput
                        ref={(input) => { this.passwordTextInput = input; }}
                        style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Şifre"
                        onChangeText={(searchString) => {this.setState({searchString})}}
                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                        secureTextEntry={true}
                        autoCapitalize = 'none'
                        autoCorrect = {false}
                        value = {this.props.r_password}
                        onChangeText={this._onPasswordChanged.bind(this)}
                    />
                </View>
                { !this.props.isloadingSignup &&
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onSignUpPress}>
                        <View style={ [buttonView, buttonViewRegister]}>
                            <View style={innerButtonView}>
                                <Icon name="ios-person-add" size={30} color="#000" />
                            </View>
                            <View style={innerButtonTextView}>
                                <Text style={{ color:'#FFF', fontSize: 15}}>Kayıt Ol</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    ||
                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <View style={ [buttonView, buttonViewRegister]}>
                            <View style={innerButtonView}>
                                <Icon name="ios-person-add" size={30} color="#000" />
                            </View>
                            <View style={innerButtonTextView}>
                                <ActivityIndicator color="white" size='small'  />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressTerms}>
                        <View style={ [termsView]}>
                            <Icon name={this.state.checkboxChecked ? 'ios-checkbox': 'ios-square-outline'} size={30} color="#000" />
                            <Text style={{ color:'#FFF', fontSize: 15, marginLeft: 10}}><Text onPress={this._onPressTermsConditions } style={{ textDecorationLine: "underline"}}> Kullanım koşullarını</Text> Kabul Ediyorum.</Text>
                        </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </LinearGradient>
      );
    }

    _onSignUpPress = () => {
        if(this.state.checkboxChecked) {
            var registerBody = {
                email: this.props.r_email,
                password: this.props.r_password,
                password_confirmation: this.props.r_password,
                name: this.props.r_name
            };
            this.props.dispatch(appActions.register(registerBody));
        } else {
            alert("Lütfen önce Kullanıcı şartlarını kabul edin.");
        }
    }

    _onEmailChanged = (email) => {
        this.props.dispatch(appActions.emailChanged(email));
    }

    _onNameChanged = (name) => {
        this.props.dispatch(appActions.nameChanged(name));
    }

    _onPasswordChanged = (password) => {
        this.props.dispatch(appActions.passwordChanged(password));
    }

    _onPressTerms = () => {
        this.setState({ checkboxChecked: !this.state.checkboxChecked })
    }

    _onPressTermsConditions = () => {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            screen: 'challenge.TermsOfUse',
            navigatorStyle: {
              navBarHidden: true
            }
          });
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    },
    scrollContainer:{
      flex: 1,
    },
    innerContainer:{
      flexDirection:'column',
      alignItems:'center',
      marginTop: height*0.08,
    },
    searchSection: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        width:width*0.7,
        marginTop:7
    },
    searchIcon: {
        paddingTop:5,
        paddingBottom:5,
        paddingLeft:10,
        paddingRight:10
    },
    input: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        color: '#424242',
        justifyContent:'center',
    },
    buttonView:{
        width: width*0.7,
        marginTop:20,
        flexDirection:'row',
      },
    buttonViewRegister:{
        backgroundColor:"#2b74a7"
    },
    innerButtonView:{
        backgroundColor:'#bab9b9',
        width:45,
        height:42,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
      },
    innerButtonTextView:{
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
      },
      termsView:{
        width: width*0.8,
        marginTop:20,
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
      }
  });


  const mapStateToProps = ({ signup }) => {
    return { r_email, r_password, r_name, isloadingSignup } = signup;
  };
  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(signupView);
```

Firstly, thanks for your response. I couldn't put the codes here because it crossed the character limit. So you can review the action content from this link. http://karahankaraman.com/actions/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating your signup page. Do you really need to dispatch to redux to handle your signup logic? You might need to show us your `actions.js` file if this continues.
Meanwhile do this:

```
{ !this.props.isloadingSignup ?
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onSignUpPress}>
                            <View style={ [buttonView, buttonViewRegister]}>
                                <View style={innerButtonView}>
                                    <Icon name="ios-person-add" size={30} color="#000" />
                                </View>
                                <View style={innerButtonTextView}>
                                    <Text style={{ color:'#FFF', fontSize: 15}}>Kayıt Ol</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        :
                        <View style={ [buttonView, buttonViewRegister]}>
                            <View style={innerButtonView}>
                                <Icon name="ios-person-add" size={30} color="#000" />
                            </View>
                            <View style={innerButtonTextView}>
                                <ActivityIndicator color="white" size='small'  />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    }
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your response. I couldn't put the codes here because it crossed the character limit. So you can review the action content from this link. http://karahankaraman.com/actions/index.js

Comment: 1) Looks like you are dispatching an error even when you get a `success` in `function login(body)` and in `function register()`. Also after dispatching `ISLOADING` you forgot to end the LOADING after you are done loading in `if ('success' in userData){}`
2) Import `Alert` and use `Alert.alert("Heading", "body")` instead of just `alert`.
3) After dispatching `R_ERROR` looks like you don't clear the errors later after handling the error. The error you dispatched remains persisted. Maybe you should add a fn that clears dispatched errors and call the fn at the start of the login and register fns